# Remote Desktop - Shift+Insert for Paste

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop, shortcut

I have a keyboard that has keys on it for copy, paste, and cut.  These keys are mapped to the following shortcuts:

ctrl-insert = copy

shift-delete = cut

shift-insert = paste

With remote desktop all this accomplishes is turning on/off insert.  Is there a way to get these shortcuts working with remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

try using http://www.autohotkey.com/ you can map pretty much any keysym to any action.
You will need to run it under the remote desktop then look at the key history to find the keysyms used by those special keys, then you can map them to whatever action or key you want.

It is possible that remote desktop is not sending those keys in which case you will quickly see that in the key history.